# Write path for logging is problematic

Tags: rsyslog

My config for my template is as follows.

```
template (name="macfilter" type="string" string="/home/pi/nas/f/remotelogs/%programname:R,ERE,0,FIELD:(([0-9A-fa-f][0-9A-fa-f]: ?[0-9A-fa-f][0-9A-fa-f]: ?[0-9A-fa-f][0-9A-fa-f]: ?[0-9A-fa-f][0-9A-fa-f]: ?[0-9A-fa-f][0-9A-fa-f]: ?[0-9A-fa-f][0-9A-fa-f])|([0-9A-Fa-f][0-9A-Fa-f][0-9A-Fa-f][0-9A-Fa-f][0-9A-Fa-f][0-9A-Fa-f][0-9A-Fa-f][0-9A-Fa-f][0-9A-Fa-f][0-9A-Fa-f][0-9A-Fa-f][0-9A-Fa-f]))--end%/%$now%.log")
*.* ?macfilter
```

My log files come in in one of many ways, but only one appears to be problematic.

This log works great, it goes to /home/pi/nas/f/0004f28210ae/date.log

```
2023-04-11T13:14:05-05:00 192.168.1.251 0004f28210ae|0411131405|clist|4|00|dbCfg: :getServerDir:Unknown dbCfg type
```

This does not. It goes to /home/pi/nas/f/2023-05-19.log

```
2023-04-06T01:00:03-05:00 075-137-050-066.res.spectrum.com [80: 5e:0c:9f:11:dc] sua [1026.2005]: FSM <6+info  > [003] allocating NICT context
```

I'm thinking it has something to do with the whitespace in the log, I've allocated for it in the regex, and the regex works according to the rsyslog regex tester, but I don't get my filepath i'm trying for.

However when i try to trim the template string in any way shape or fashion it tells me extra stuff in my template, ignoring the extra stuff.

Any ideas? Am I even approaching this in the simplest fashion?

EDIT:

The two comments below were how I fixed it.

Comment: if ($rawmsg contains "64167f" or $rawmsg contains "0004f2" or $rawmsg contains "9cadef" or $rawmsg contains "482567" or $rawmsg contains "80:") then {
        if ($rawmsg contains "80:") then {
            set $!nameval0 = replace($rawmsg, " ", "");
            set $!nameval = replace($!nameval0, ":", "");
        } else {
                set $!nameval = $app-name;
            }
    }  else {
    set $!nameval = $app-name;
}

Comment: template (name="macfilter" type="string" string="/home/pi/nas/f/remotelogs/%$!nameval:R,ERE,0,FIELD:([0-9A-Fa-f][0-9A-Fa-f][0-9A-Fa-f][0-9A-Fa-f][0-9A-Fa-f][0-9A-Fa-f][0-9A-Fa-f][0-9A-Fa-f][0-9A-Fa-f][0-9A-Fa-f][0-9A-Fa-f][0-9A-Fa-f])--end%/%$now%.log")
*.* -?macfilter

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($rawmsg contains "64167f" or $rawmsg contains "0004f2" or $rawmsg contains "9cadef" or $rawmsg contains "482567" or $rawmsg contains "80:") then {
        if ($rawmsg contains "80:") then {
            set $!nameval0 = replace($rawmsg, " ", "");
            set $!nameval = replace($!nameval0, ":", "");
        } else {
                set $!nameval = $app-name;
            }
    }  else {
    set $!nameval = $app-name;
}

template (name="macfilter" type="string" string="/home/pi/nas/f/remotelogs/%$!nameval:R,ERE,0,FIELD:([0-9A-Fa-f][0-9A-Fa-f][0-9A-Fa-f][0-9A-Fa-f][0-9A-Fa-f][0-9A-Fa-f][0-9A-Fa-f][0-9A-Fa-f][0-9A-Fa-f][0-9A-Fa-f][0-9A-Fa-f][0-9A-Fa-f])--end%/%$now%.log")
*.* -?macfilter
```

Comment: Note, for an ERE regexp you can use the suffix group multiplier of form `{min,max}` or `{count}`.  Replace the repeated `[0-9A-Fa-f]` sequence by `[0-9A-Fa-f]{12}`.